# Passing current username in location.href in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Is it possible to do? I want to pass a user to a servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/profile")
```

so that the URL would be like this: `/profile?username=currentusername`

I tried:

```
 <%
        HttpSession session1 = request.getSession(false);
        String username = (String) session1.getAttribute("username");
    %>
        <div class="navbar-item"
             onclick="location.href =
     '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/profile?username=${requestScope.username}'

            My profile
        </div>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You are getting this value in `doGet` method of servlet or not? Also, does the link take you to required servlet or not?

Comment: @Swati I access the request parameteres and atributes in servlets using `request.getAttribute()` and `request.getParameter()`.